# How to suppress seaborn output when recalling figure object with regplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot data to a figure and respective axis in matplotlib and as new work comes up, recall the figure with the additional plot on the axis:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

x=np.arange(0,20)
y=2*x

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,x)

ax.scatter(x,y)
fig
```

Which works fine with matplotlib, if I however use seaborn's regplot:

```
fig2,ax2=plt.subplots()
sns.regplot(x,x,ax=ax2,fit_reg=False)

sns.regplot(x,y,ax=ax2,fit_reg=False)
fig2
```

fig2 generates the figure that I want but the regplot command generates an empty figure. Is there a way to suppress the regplot's empty output or have it display the updated ax2 without recalling fig2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are using the jupyter notebook with the inline backend. In some circumstances `regplot` triggers the creation of a new figure even if the artists are being added to the previous one and this messes up the output. I don't know why this happens but I found a workaround that might help you, using `plt.ioff` to temporarily disable automatic display of figures.

```
plt.ioff()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.regplot(x, x, ax=ax)
fig

sns.regplot(x, 2 * x, ax=ax)
fig
```

You have to call [`plt.ioff`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ioff) before creating the figure for this to work. After that you have to explicitly display the figure. Then you can call [`plt.ion`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ion) to restore the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank Goyo, like you say not the solution but a good workaround thank you!

Answer (score 0):

regplot does not generate an empty figure. According to the documentation:

> Understanding the difference between regplot() and lmplot() can be a
>   bit tricky. In fact, they are closely related, as lmplot() uses
>   regplot() internally and takes most of its parameters. However,
>   regplot() is an axes-level function, so it draws directly onto an axes
>   (either the currently active axes or the one provided by the ax
>   parameter), while lmplot() is a figure-level function and creates its
>   own figure, which is managed through a FacetGrid.

When I do the following:

```
fig2,ax2 = plt.subplots()
same_fig2 = sns.regplot(x,x,ax=ax2,fit_reg=False)

same_fig2.figure is fig2
>>> True
```

Comment: It could be the fact that I am running the above in a jupyter notebook, however if i run sns.regplot(x,y,ax=ax2,fit_reg=False) in a separate cell to

Comment: the preceding code then an empty figure is generated.