# seaborn stop figure from being visualized

Tags: python, seaborn

A figure generated with seaborn is being visualized, even without f.show().

I want the figure to be only visualized when i call it.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def plot_kde_x (x):
    sns.set(style="ticks")
    
    f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, 
                                        gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.15, .85)})

    sns.boxplot(x, ax=ax_box)
    sns.kdeplot(x, ax=ax_hist)

    ax_box.set(yticks=[])
    sns.despine(ax=ax_hist)
    sns.despine(ax=ax_box, left=True)
    return f 


x = np.random.randint(1,10,100)
# figure should not be displayed
f = plot_kde_x(x)
```

OUT, figure still displayed
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem occurs because `matplotlib` is using the `%matplotlib inline` backend [automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43028034/9152905). This automatically creates the plot and embeds it in the Jupyter document.

You can temporarily [disable/enable the inline creation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41214074/9152905) with `plt.ioff()` and `plt.ion()`. Note that `f.show()` won't work with the inline-backend, but you can simply call `f` to see the plot.

Here is a full working example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def plot_kde_x (x):
    plt.ioff()
    sns.set(style="ticks")
    
    f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, 
                                        gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.15, .85)})

    sns.boxplot(x, ax=ax_box)
    sns.kdeplot(x, ax=ax_hist)

    ax_box.set(yticks=[])
    sns.despine(ax=ax_hist)
    sns.despine(ax=ax_box, left=True)
    plt.ion()
    return f


x = np.random.randint(1,10,100)
# figure should not be displayed
f = plot_kde_x(x)
f
```

Comment: You are welcome, it was super helpful that you provided a working example :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jupyter, the plot is shown twice because `plot_kde_x(x)` returns the figure.

Either remove the return, or, if you still want to be able to catch the figure object, add `;` after the function:

```
plot_kde_x(x);
```

Or assign to a variable:

```
f = plot_kde_x(x)
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to stop the first display (while it is being created)? 

if i do f = plot_kde_x(x), I would like it to display 0 times, just like if i used plotly

Comment: I have edited for clairty, makitn the question "never visualize the figure unsless f.show() is caled